# questions about knapsack?

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

Good day,

The knapsack algorithms doesn't quite "click" in my head. I know how to answer the knapsack problem questions of different variations (0-1 knapsack, spice-carrying knapsack etc) very well, yet I don't exactly understand the algorithm itself; and I would love to fill in the gap

To keep my question less vague, I broke my question down to a few subquestions. Also Here is my typical answer to the knapsack problem at the exam,

> Construct X-dimensional matrix (where X is a number of variables to keep an eye on). From point 0 {0,0,...0}, calculate neighbouring nodes, and then from the results obtained, will the next diagonal point in the matrix with the result giving by far the most optimal solution. Repeat until all considered options in the algorithm are exahusted

- How do we know the knapsack algorithm works (aside from empirical observations)? In particular, how do we exactly know that there isn't an optional configuration considered s.t. it yields a more optimal result than our algorithm returns in the end?
- Using the "X-dimensional matrix" seems very redundant memory usage-wise, is there a more optimal data structure for the knapsack problem? Perhaps a min-max binary tree (something that "seems" more optimal for this case)
- Suppose we have a very large knapsack. Wouldn't that be more efficient to fill up the knapsack with a greedy approach (with item giving the best ratio), until there is only very little space left? In my mind, until here is `2*(largest item)` of space left?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Since the knapsack algorithm is a greedy algorithm, we know that the algorithm has the greedy choice property (also makes a choice for some optimal solution) and it has optimal substructure. Thus there could not be a more optimal result because our algorithm always chooses the optimal decision.